# Jquery Mobile "tap" event bug

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery, event-propagation

Note***: Have to test it on tablet, I only tested it on Ipad

1 touch will fire different events of different object at the same sport

http://jsfiddle.net/wR6dK/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
```

JS:

```
$("#box1").on('tap',function(){
    $("#log").append('box1 clicked <br>');
    $(this).fadeOut(0);
});

$("#box2").on('tap',function(){
    $("#log").append('box2 clicked <br>');
    $(this).fadeOut(0);
});
```

this case the green box is hidden... it can move away or rearrange the z-index, all will trigger the red box's event with a single touch

Is it how it works? is it happening with "vclick" and other events as well?

Is it a bug?

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. No, that's not what happens when clicking it, and that's definitely not the desired behavior. That seems weird. It only happens to me when I tap in the overlapping part. Is that what you see happening?

Comment: @Ian YES!!! That's the one screws up my site

Answer (score 2):

This is one of an oldest javascript errors, never fixed because it wasn't know for a long time. To make a story short, javascript was never meant to be used like this, but give man a tool and he will bend it to its needs thus we have frameworks like jQuery and jQuery Mobile.

This is also called a fall through event. It can be prevented with this functions:

- **[stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)**
- **[stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/)**

and return false.

This is your example modified to work with this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/wR6dK/5/

```
$("#box1").on('tap',function(e){
    $("#log").append('box1 clicked <br>');
    $(this).fadeOut(0);
    e.stopPropagation();   
    return false;    
});

$("#box2").on('tap',function(e){
    $("#log").append('box2 clicked <br>');
    $(this).fadeOut(0);
    e.stopPropagation();   
    return false;    
});
```

Let me show you another example so you can understand this problem in case of jQuery Mobile: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Xz2np/

```
$('#page1').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){
    $('.someDiv').live('click', function (e) {   
        alert('Event is not going to propagate to content div, thus not hiding a header');             
        event.stopPropagation();   
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
});
```

To understand this problem, just click on a DIV example then comment those 2 lines, again run an example and again click on a DIV. And please I know live is deprecated in jQuery 1.9 but this is my old example.

Comment: as far as i'm concerned, stopPropagation is to prevent event from "bubbling" to its parent. box1 and box2 are siblings of the same parent. Did anyone test it out on the tablet?

Comment: forget about the first haft of my previous comment, but it's not happening with normal click events, only tap, so I don't think it's the problem...